# LoginView Control in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, loginview

I want to access the text written in AnonymousTemplate of LoginView Control through Code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You convert your the Login to visible template, and you must see something like:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" >
            <tr>
                <td>
             ...
             <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
             ....
```

then on code behind you find your control as:

```
TextBox TheUserName = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
```

where you place the correct user id, of your control that you wish to grab and change.